# sed command is not working properly when using wildcard

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, wildcard

I am trying to use 'sed' command to delete the last line of the files that matches the wildcard pattern given as command line argument and the move the file from that directory to the present directory. The code is as follow:

```
DIR="/home/usr_name/trash/"
for file in "$@"
    do
        if [ $file != "-h" ] //ignore this line
        then
            temp="$DIR$file"
            sed '$d' "$DIR$file"
            mv $temp .
        fi
    done
```

The code is moving the file but its not executing the 'sed' command to delete the last line. Giving the wildcard as **ab*** , it gives the following error:

```
sed: can't read /home/usr_name/trash/ab*: No such file or directory
```

Help me to figure out this situation.

Comment: @sergio ab* means that I want to move all those files whose names start with ab.

Comment: Btw.: Take a look at sed's option `-i`.

Comment: Globing is done by the shell, "$DIR$file" is quoted so the file is not found.

Comment: So, the files start in trash (`$DIR`), are supposed to be edited inline by sed, and then moved from trash to whichever directory you ran the script from?

Comment: `sed` without the `-i` option doesn't change the file itself, it sends the edited version to standard output. I think you either need to use `sed -i` (which does an in-place edit), or use `sed '$d' "$DIR$file" >"$file"` to  leave the trash file in place and put an edited version in the current directory. BTW, there are several places where you should have double-quotes around a variable reference; I recommend [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) for pointing out problems like this.

Comment: @GordonDavisson quoting the "$DIR$file" is exactly what generates the problem.

Comment: @Sorin Huh? Variables which contain file names should *always, always* be quoted.

Comment: @tripleee this variable contains a wildcard that the asker wants expanded, which as I said is handled by the shell, sed doesn't know how to expand it which is why it searching for an file with the exact name '/home/usr_name/trash/ab*'

Answer (score 0):

If you need wildcards, the simplest solution would be to use find:

```
find "$DIR" -name "$file" \
   -exec sed -i '$d' {} \; 
   -exec mv {} "$DEST" \;
```

- `-name "$file"` - this will tell find to search for files matching the wildcard
- `-exec sed -i '$d' {} \;`- execute sed on each file found `{}` represents the file
- `-exec mv {} "$DEST" \;` - move the file

note that the order of execs mater, after the move the file will not be available in the old location.

**Edit:** I initially assumed that the `'ab*'` was given as a quoted parameter to the entire script. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60236879/939457) reminded me of another possibility: you run the script from a directory where there aren't any files starting with 'ab', in which case 'ab*' doesn't get expanded, and mv will work in your script, but sed not (since you quote the "$DIR$file", see the debugging output of bash:

```
sorin@testvm ~/tmp $ seq 1 2 > src/ab1
sorin@testvm ~/tmp $ seq 1 4 > src/ab5
sorin@testvm ~/tmp $ seq 1 3 > src/ab3
sorin@testvm ~/tmp $ bash -x test.sh ab*
+ DIR=src/
+ for file in '"$@"'
+ '[' 'ab*' '!=' -h ']'
+ temp='src/ab*'
+ sed '$d' 'src/ab*'
sed: can't read src/ab*: No such file or directory
+ mv src/ab1 src/ab3 src/ab5 .
sorin@testvm ~/tmp $
```

This covers exactly the scenario described in your question.

Answer (score 0):

When you run

```
yourcript ab*
```

the shell attempts to expand the wildcard in the current directory, then passes in the result as `"$@"`. If there are no matches in the current directory, the *expanded* wildcard (in the shell's traditional default configuration) is now the *literal* string `ab*`, and no further wildcard expansion will be attempted.

(Bash has `nullglob` to change this behavior, so that a wildcard which doesn't match any files gets replaced with nothing; but that doesn't really help here.)

If the wildcard *does* match some files, chances are that those files won't exist in the other directory, 
or (in the general case) that the files with those names will not be the files you actually wanted to process.

In the worst case, maybe there *are* some files in the current directory which match the wildcard *and* they all duplicate files with the same name in the destination directory. So if you have `ab` and `abc` both in the current directory and in the other directory, but the other directory also contains `abecedary` and `abugida`, your command will only process the first two, and you will receive no warning that the other two were never matched and processed.

Bottom line, probably rethink your approach to pass the full path to the files you want to process into the script; then, the rest is easy, and your script's behavior will be predictable, and consistent with how other file-processing utilities behave.

You'll still need to make `sed` actually modify each file. Just `sed '$d' files` will not change `files`, just print the modified contents to standard output. If you have `sed -i`, probably use that.

```sh
for file in "$@"
do
    # Note added quotes
    if [ "$file" != "-h" ] # ignore this line
    then
        sed -i '$d' "$file"
        mv "$file" .
    fi
done
```

Usage:

```
yourscript /home/usr_name/trash/ab*
```

Comment: Right, sorry about the mess i did here. I deleted my post.

Comment: @Jetchisel I liked the basic idea of your answer; it really would not have deserved so many downvotes. `ed` is decidedly a fringe tool in this day and age, so probably several of the downvoters didn't really understand what you were suggesting.